# Creating DATETIME from DATE and TIME

Tags: mysql, datetime

Is there way in MySQL to create DATETIME from a given attribute of type DATE and a given attribute of type TIME?

Comment: But why would you do that?

Comment: I would do that because software I didn't write produced a MySQL table in which the right times of day were combined with the wrong dates. However, an automatic timestamp field has the right dates, so I wanted to merge the right dates with the right times to correct the table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
datetime = CONCAT(date, ' ', time);
```

Comment: Be aware that `CONCAT()` returns a string, no a *true* `DATETIME` value.

Comment: CONCAT is poor - what if time is > 24 hours?

Comment: This is wrong, and absolutely not the way to do this, the result will be a string and the return type asked for was explicitly a DATETIME not a varchar.

As @SystemParadox mentions, the way to do this is by using the proper datatypes and add them together.

Comment: @ChristopherBonitz You can reach the aim with this solution as well, then you need another function that makes that string a datetime again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54090797/11154841).

Answer (score 68):

Copied from the MySQL Documentation:

[TIMESTAMP(expr), TIMESTAMP(expr1,expr2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)

> With a single argument, this function returns the date or datetime expression expr as a datetime value. With two arguments, it adds the time expression expr2 to the date or datetime expression expr1 and returns the result as a datetime value.

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMP('2003-12-31');
    -> '2003-12-31 00:00:00'
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMP('2003-12-31 12:00:00','12:00:00');
    -> '2004-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: This is close to be correct, but in mysql there exists two datatypes for this, being datetime and timestamp.

As this is actually returning a timestamp, it is not answering the question, but it gets close.

Comment: @ChristopherBonitz you are correct that mysql has both TIMESTAMP and DATETIME, however the name of this function is misleading, it actually does return a DATETIME, if mysql had simply named it datetime() I think people would be much less confused.

Answer (score 46):

To get a *true* `DATETIME` value from your two separate `DATE` and `TIME` values:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Comment: What is the timezone with this attempt?

Comment: I guess it will be the one set in [`time_zone` system variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone). `DATETIME` type doesn't store time zone.

Comment: CONCAT is poor - use datetime functions for datetime manipulation and string functions for string manipulation.

Answer (score 31):

You could use `ADDTIME()`:

```
ADDTIME(CONVERT(date, DATETIME), time)
```

- `date` may be a date string or a `DATE` object.
- `time` may be a time string  or a `TIME` object.

Tested in MySQL 5.5.

Comment: This is the way to do this, you can quickly verify it by running this SELECT ADDTIME(CONVERT(DATE('2018-05-21'), DATETIME), TIME('10:57'))

Answer (score 1):

```
select timestamp('2003-12-31 12:00:00','12:00:00');
```

works, when the string is formatted correctly. Otherwise, you can just include the time using str_to_date.

```
select str_to_date('12/31/2003 14:59','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i');
```

Comment: This makes it possible to use an indexed datetime column for a comparision with a fixed and self-built date. Let us say you want only records of today, but you only have a datetime column at hand. Then you cannot use `NOW() - interval 1 day` but instead you can create your own "yesterday midnight" datetime as a string and make it a datetime with the `str_to_date` function.

Answer (score 0):

Without creating and parsing strings, just add an interval to the date:

```
set @dt_text = '1964-05-13 15:34:05.757' ;
set @d = date(@dt_text) ;
set @t = time(@dt_text) ;
select @d, @t, @d + interval time_to_sec( @t ) second;
```

However this truncates the microseconds.

I agree with Muki - be sure to take account of time zones and daylight savings time!