# Query for choose all orders from all restaurants for the current day

Tags: mysql

How can I write a mysql query that will choose all the orders of all restaurants for the current day?

**Some restaurants may close after 24:00.**

So I have three tables:

1. `restaurants` with some fields [`id`, ]
2. `orders` with some fields [`id, resid, orderdate,` ]
3. `hours` with some fields [`id, resid, day, open, close`] the `day` is a number from 0-6, the open and close are time between `00:00:00` and `23:59:59`

Thank you

This is what about i need

```
SELECT b.*
FROM restaurants a, orders b, hours c
WHERE a.id=b.resid
AND a.id=c.resid
```

---- here i need the code that will choose the orders for the current working day of the restaurant, but the current working day may include some orders from the previous calendar day if the restaurant close after 24:00

Comment: Inner Join WHERE open interval close =1day

Comment: resid? how lazy is that? Apart from that, you have to decide what constitutes 'a day' in your schema. Otherwise you will inevitable count the same order twice.

Comment: Mihai what is this????? can you write an answer?

Comment: I think this is a good question but lack of information to clearly understand. @Teodoros please update your question, add example, study case, some data, etc,. to easy to understand. You can update question title also to something general, that will help to.

Comment: The question has been edited, but not really improved. Heed @Hardy's advice!

Comment: Mr Strawberry, do you have something to propose? how would you like to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
   " SELECT b.*".
   " FROM orders b, rests a, times c ".
   " WHERE a.id=b.resid ".
   " AND a.id=c.resid ".
   " AND (".
        "( c.day=dayofweek(subdate(current_date, 1))-1 " .
        " AND c.close < c.open " .
        " AND c.close> TIME(NOW())" .
        " AND b.orderdate>= CONCAT(subdate(current_date, 1),' ',c.open) )" .
        " OR " .
        "( c.day=dayofweek(current_date)-1 " .
        " AND c.close >= c.open " .
        " AND c.close> TIME(NOW())" .
        " AND b.orderdate>= CONCAT(current_date,' ',c.open) )" .
        " OR " .
        "( c.day=dayofweek(current_date)-1 " .
        " AND c.close < c.open " .
        " AND CONCAT(ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1),' ',c.close)> TIME(NOW())" . 
        " AND b.orderdate>= CONCAT(current_date,' ',c.open) )" .
        ")";
```

Comment: WEEKDAY() may be better approach, what meaning of `c.close < c.open=TRUE`, is it okay to compare date and string `b.orderdate>= CONCAT(subdate(current_date, 1),' ',c.open) )`

Comment: if you run this query for report, note that your query include restaurant which will close yet, mean that restaurant data in not complete for a day. your report can be incorrect.

Comment: Hardy, thanks for your notes. Do you think that this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318630/creating-datetime-from-date-and-time is not right?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select o.*
from orders o
where o.orderdate = curdate();
```

If not, can you modify your question to better explain what you want?

Comment: thanks for your answer. This is not what i want because if one restaurant close after 24:00, lets say 2:00 and now is 1:00 this query don't include the orders before 24:00. When i say current day i mean current working day for restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not give much information, so I make 2 assumption here

Assumption 1: You run this query at 1AM and want to get all order your 1AM yesterday till now
Assumption 2: No restaurant open 24h day

```
hours.day =  WEEKDAY(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)
```

If hours.close < hours.open mean restaurant open from YESTERDAY + open_time to TODAY + close_time, otherwise it is open and close on YESTERDAY

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), CASE WHEN c.close < c.open THEN  1 ELSE 0 END), '%Y%m%d'), c.close), '%Y%m%d%T')
```

So your query is something like

```
SELECT b.*
FROM restaurants a, orders b
WHERE a.id=b.resid
AND a.id in (
    select c.resid
    from hours c
    where c.day =  WEEKDAY(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)
    and STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1), '%Y%m%d'), c.open), '%Y%m%d%T') > SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)
    and STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), CASE WHEN c.close < c.open THEN  1 ELSE 0 END), '%Y%m%d'), c.close), '%Y%m%d%T') <= CURDATE()
    )
```

I'm not sure about `orders.orderdate`, so you should update your filter on `orders` table to get correct data you want.

Hope this help

Comment: Hi hardy, thanks for your answer. I think you try to find open restaurants into your subquery but i want all the orders of all restaurants even they are closed, but beyond that i have tried this query and always return orders from all restaurants even they are open or closed. Your assumptions are right

Comment: Sorry for the above, of course i want orders from open restaurants for the current day