# How to test if there are overlapping periods with a particular period?

Tags: mysql, overlap

In my table there are two columns of type date and two columns of type time :

[image]

Here are some records of the table :

[image]

Now , in my web app I want to insert a new row in that table :

[image]

When submitting the form I want to count the number of rows where the entered period overlaps to others that are already in the database table ; by period I mean a ( beginning_date , beginning_time ) and a ( ending_date , ending_time ) together , for example ( 2016-03-15 , 12:00:00 ) and ( 2016-03-17 , 10:00:00 ).

I tried this query but it does not give the right results :

```
select count(identifiant) from reservation_table where ( (date_debut <= '2016-03-14' and heure_debut <= '01:00:00') and (date_fin <= '2016-03-14' and heure_fin <= '03:00:00') and (date_fin > '2016-03-14' and heure_fin > '01:00:00') ) or 
( (date_debut >= '2016-03-14' and heure_debut >= '01:00:00') and (date_fin >= '2016-03-14' and heure_fin >= '03:00:00') and (date_debut < '2016-03-14' and heure_debut < '03:00:00') ) or 
( (date_debut >= '2016-03-14' and heure_debut >= '01:00:00') and (date_fin <= '2016-03-14' and heure_fin <= '03:00:00') ) or 
( (date_debut <= '2016-03-14' and heure_debut <= '01:00:00') and (date_fin >= '2016-03-14' and heure_fin >= '03:00:00') );
```

To have a better understanding about the period overlapping here is an image :

[image]

So in this image the red period is the period entered from the web app , and the black periods are those already in the database. So how to get all periods that overlap to a particular period ?

Comment: Your code would be a lot simpler if you just had a 'datetime' column. This code would create the column for you:
UPDATE table SET datetime_field = CONCAT(date_field, " ", time_field);

Also you appear to have double quotation marks " before each semicolon, are these supposed to be two single quotes ' '? Sorry if that's a mysql thing, I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: ok , the double-quotes were used because i constructed the query from a PHP variable.

Comment: so how to test the period overlapping if working with `datetime` columns ?

Comment: I've added the overlap tag to your question. read it's wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to test if two elements overlap is to check if the one starts before the second ends, while the second starts before the first ends, as mentioned in the [overlap](/questions/tagged/overlap) tag [wiki.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info)
I don't have much experience with MySql but did find [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318630/creating-datetime-from-date-and-time) to create a `datetime` value from `date` and `time`:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Once you have datetime values you can do this:

```
select count(identifiant) 
from reservation_table 
where @YourStartDatetime <= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date_fin,' ', heure_fin), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
and @YourEndDateTime >=  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date_debut ,' ', heure_debut), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

if the count returns 0, then you have no records overlapping the period specified by `@YourStartDatetime` and `@YourEndDateTime`