# SQL: Select * WHERE due date and due time after NOW() without DATETIME()

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

I am trying to select * tasks that are not due. That been said, anything thats past this exact date **and time** should be selected taking in consideration that I have a separate columns for date and time.

Currently I am using this where **it does not** select all instances of today:

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `due_date` >= NOW() AND `due_time` >= NOW()
```

I have no access in alternating the database for a DATETIME field. I can only select.

The ***due_date*** has **DATE** as type and ***due_time*** has **TIME** as type

Comment: Also note that you will miss all the tasks that are dued later than today (as date) but earlier than now (as time)

Comment: Not 100% sure this is a duplicate, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318630/creating-datetime-from-date-and-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the behavior it seems like you're looking for, you could do something like this:

```
  SELECT t.* FROM `tasks` t
   WHERE t.`due_date` >= DATE(NOW())
     AND (  ( t.`due_date` = DATE(NOW()) AND t.`due_time` >= TIME(NOW()) )
         OR ( t.`due_date` > DATE(NOW()) )
         )
```

The first cut is the comparison to due_date, all tasks that are due today or later.  That includes too many, we need to get rid of tasks that are due today but before the current time.

There are other query approaches that may seem "simpler". The approach above keeps the predicates on bare columns, so MySQL can make effective use of range scan operations on suitable indexes.

**FOLLOWUP**

I've done this type of query before, for paging with multiple columns in the key. Something was bothering me about that original query, it had more conditions than were really required. (What threw me off was the >= condition on  due_time.)

I believe this is equivalent:

```
  SELECT t.* FROM `tasks` t
   WHERE t.`due_date` >= DATE(NOW())
     AND ( t.`due_date` > DATE(NOW()) OR t.`due_time` >= TIME(NOW()) )
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you. Can I sort everything by date first and time then?

Comment: Yes, `ORDER BY due_date ASC, due_time ASC` should work just fine.

Comment: Play with the ordering. I typically find DESC to be more useful when playing with dates.

Comment: The original query in my answer has a redundant condition that can be removed. Modified query added as a followup.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `due_date` >= DATE(NOW()) AND `due_time` >= TIME(NOW());
```

DATE() extracts the year-month-date part, and TIME() the hours:mins:secs part

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Dave's answer is cleaner, use his.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work either. It selects thats due TODAY and from now on

Comment: That's the >=, try >

Comment: This misses some tasks that are due (e.g. tomorrow before due_time).

Comment: @spencer7593 I am only trying to select all "active" tasks

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ try this so we can see something to work with. Doesn't have to be extensive, but have some legit dummy data and schema

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CURDATE()` and `CURTIME()` instead.  You should be able to work out the logic having those at your disposal.

More details here:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp

Though per the comments, it's usually ideal to keep a datetime version of things you want to compare against a datetime.  Then, you could just do a single compare and use `NOW()` like you are now.

Comment: I tried CURDATE() and CURTIME() too. I get same results.

Comment: I have no access to the database to alternate it (as per said on my updated question), and only SELECT is my choice to go

Comment: In your case, I understand, but many other people will read this question/answer in search for how to do what you're doing and they WILL have access.  So it's worth mentioning even though it might not related directly to your question.

Comment: spencers answer is what I was looking for. Thank you