# Order mysql query by date and time which are separate columns

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

I wish to order my mySQL query by date and time as if they were a combine column (datetime) however they are a separate column (Date and Time). I need to be able to display all the records from a table that are after the current time (using Date("")).

Comment: use: **SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE ... ORDER BY datefield,timefield;**

Comment: Uh, `ORDER BY mydate, mytime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume you have table `t`  with structure:

```
id | date | time
```

Then to order by date and time you do:

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY date,time
```

To select everything that's newer than the current time do:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE date > CURDATE() OR (date = CURDATE() AND time > CURTIME())
```

There's an alternative way to do the second one which is based on [Creating DATETIME from DATE and TIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318630/creating-datetime-from-date-and-time) so you can refer to that if you need to.

You can combine the above and do a :

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE date > CURDATE() OR (date = CURDATE() AND time > CURTIME()) ORDER BY date,time
```

Comment: EDIT: Turns out it works perfectly :D Timezone difference between myself and the server caused me to think that it wasn't. Appreciate the help!