# How to compare with time range with a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this table in my `MySQL` database:

```
   ID   First_Name  Date_Serve     Time_Serve   RFID_Tag    Amount_Serve
   --------------------------------------------------------------
    1     John      17-11-2018      10:00:00    hdgdYun8JH   Small
    2     George    18-11-2018      11:00:00    kdjfHluhHB    Big
```

and have this code for `MySQL` query:

```vb
Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    Dim str As String = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=testdb;Uid=root;Pwd=password123"

    Using con As New MySqlConnection(str)
        Dim query As String = 
            "select * from testdata where rfid_tag='" & TextBox3.Text & 
            "' and Date_Serve= '" & Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd ") & 
            "' and Time_Serve= '" & Date.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss ") & 
            "' or amount_serve=''"

        Dim cm As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        con.Open()

        Dim rd As MySqlDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader()

        ' Check if any rows exist
        If rd.Read() Then
            If rd.GetString(3) = "small" Then
                MessageBox.Show("small")
            ElseIf rd.GetString(3) = "Big" Then
                MessageBox.Show("big")
            ElseIf rd.GetString(3) = "Midium" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Mid")
            End If
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

What I am looking for to do is with time to make like delay 15 minutes from `time_serve`.
For example if the time is `10:00:00 AM` need to serve him his amount at `10 AM` until `10:15 AM`.
How can I achieve this?

With my code, I can serve him at exact time but I need something like a range.

Comment: would something like `ADD_DATE` help? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

There you could ask if a certain time rate is between time_serve and the extra time that you have allotted

This would then probably be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM testdata 
         WHERE @0 BETWEEN TIMESTAMP( Date_Serve, Time_Serve ) 
               AND DATE_ADD( TIMESTAMP( Date_Serve, Time_Serve), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE ) )
```

Where `@0` would be the argument for the current datetime that you could add to your query itself. From what is visible from your code, you shouldn't just use string concatination to build the query string itself, just have a look at MySqlParamater and how you can use them with your query (but I know that is not part of the question)

Note that I am uncertain on what would be the best to convert your date & time columns into a DATETIME statement, there seems to be some [confusion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318630/creating-datetime-from-date-and-time). Alternatively, you could also just check between for the `Time_Serve` field if `Date_Serve` is also an argument to your query

Comment: I did it like this format bu didn't work `Dim query As String = "select * from testdata where getdate() BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(Time_Serve ) and
               rfid_tag='" & TextBox3.Text & "' 
               and Date_Serve= '" & Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd ") & "'
               and DATE_ADD( TIMESTAMP(Time_Serve), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) or spring_size='' "`

Comment: @MohammadKhaled but your query is incorrect, the between is preceded with one expression and followed by start and end (so 2 arguments separated by AND), check the link I provided with it. Your rfid entry has nothing to do with the time_serve