# How to get time from next date in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, grouping, time-and-attendance

I have table `Att_Log` like this:

| Emp_ID | Date_Att | Time_Att |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E-0123 | 2024-01-02 | 08:05:56 |
| E-0123 | 2024-01-02 | 17:02:23 |
| E-0124 | 2024-01-02 | 21:55:56 |
| E-0124 | 2024-01-03 | 06:02:23 |

the results I expect is like this:

| Emp_ID | Date | In_Time | Out_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E-0123 | 2024-01-02 | 08:05:56 | 17:02:23 |
| E-0124 | 2024-01-02 | 21:55:56 | 06:02:23 |

get the `min(Time_Att)` as `Out_Time` from following `Date_Att` if the `In_Time` is >= 21:00:00

How to query in MySQL server?

I can query the min and max `Time_Att` with this query:

`SELECT Emp_ID, Date_Att, Min(Time_Att) AS InTime, Max(Time_Att) AS OutTime FROM Att_Log`

but I don't know how to get the above result. If anyone can help, I would highly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: SQL doesn't really have the concept of a "next row" -- SQL records are by definition unordered.  This would be easy if you were querying this from a programming language.  Are you doing that?

Comment: ok, I understand, so there is no possible query that can be used for the results I expect? Actually, I made the program in VB, but I think it would be neater if I could display the table through a query in MySQL

Comment: Storing date and time separately is an architectural error in most cases. Combine them to one datetime value for each source row then sort.

Comment: What does `EMP_ID` stand for ? From the sample data, only two rows are provided for a given `EMP_ID`, which I assume is a session_id that consists of a start datetime and an end datetime. Is this the case for all?

Comment: So you're not recording whether an entry is for clock-in or clock-out?

Comment: @blabla_bingo emp_id is employee id, and this program will be used for attendance system

Comment: @Salman A yes, the machine can record the clock-in entry and clock-out entry, but I want to make it more automatic, so when there is user error the query still can show the proper record

Comment: Your problem description is incomplete. Your sample data makes it look like there are always two rows per emp_id, but your last comment suggests there can be many more.  Then in your sample result you are only showing the out time not the out date. Does this mean that there can only be two rows per employee and date and an exit is always on the same day as the entry without exeption? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77903908/edit) your request to add that information. Also add data to your sample data to illustrate this. Are there edge cases, like a missing exit, that must be considered?

Answer (score 1):

As the OP said in comments that the emp_id stands for employee_id, so this means there can be more attendance instances for an employee than the current sample table shows.

And since there is no `attendance_id` column which identifies an attendance(i.e a att_id records the In_Time and the same att_id that records the Out_Time), therefore, unless there is a clear principle that handles the case when an employee fails to register on the machine at an anticipated clock-out time, here I can only assume that there is no missing clock-out record. In this case, a given attentance should always be elicited in a pair, which consists of a row that represents the clock-in and the following row that represents the clock-out, then the row right after it represents another attendance record's clock-in,etc. And should the total number of rows for an emp_id is odd, it means there is an on-going attendance which has yet to clock out.

**If the case above is true**, then I suppose the `min` and `max` aggregate function for an emp_id is not helpful in deducing the clock-in and clock-out of an attendance if there are more than 2 rows for that emp_id. On the other hand, we need to rely on the sequence of (Date_Att,Time_Att) in ascending order to cover the ground.

The query involves 2 steps. First of all, get the sequence of Date_Att,Time_Att in ascending order for every emp_id. The result is stored in a CTE table. Then perform an outer join on two of the same CTE tables which matches a row of odd sequence to a row of even sequence.

```
create table Att_Log (Emp_ID varchar(10),   Date_Att date,  Time_Att time);

-- let's add more rows to your sample data to make it more realistic
insert Att_Log values
('E-0123','2024-01-02','08:05:56'),
('E-0123','2024-01-02','17:02:23'),
('E-0124','2024-01-02','21:55:56'),
('E-0124','2024-01-03','06:02:23'),
('E-0123','2024-01-03','17:02:23'),
('E-0124','2024-01-04','09:02:23'),
('E-0124','2024-01-04','11:02:23')
;

select * from att_log;

-- result
+--------+------------+----------+
| Emp_ID | Date_Att   | Time_Att |
+--------+------------+----------+
| E-0123 | 2024-01-02 | 08:05:56 |
| E-0123 | 2024-01-02 | 17:02:23 |
| E-0124 | 2024-01-02 | 21:55:56 |
| E-0124 | 2024-01-03 | 06:02:23 |
| E-0123 | 2024-01-03 | 17:02:23 |
| E-0124 | 2024-01-04 | 09:02:23 |
| E-0124 | 2024-01-04 | 11:02:23 |
+--------+------------+----------+

with cte as(
    select emp_id, date_att, time_att, 
    row_number() over(partition by emp_id order by date_att,time_att) as att_seq
    from att_log 
    )
select c1.emp_id, c1.date_att as `date`, c1.time_att as in_time,c2.time_att as out_time
from cte c1 left join cte c2
on c1.emp_id=c2.emp_id and c1.att_seq=c2.att_seq - 1
where c1.att_seq mod 2 = 1
;

-- result
+--------+------------+----------+----------+
| emp_id | date       | in_time  | out_time |
+--------+------------+----------+----------+
| E-0123 | 2024-01-02 | 08:05:56 | 17:02:23 |
| E-0123 | 2024-01-03 | 17:02:23 | NULL     |
| E-0124 | 2024-01-02 | 21:55:56 | 06:02:23 |
| E-0124 | 2024-01-04 | 09:02:23 | 11:02:23 |
+--------+------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: this is the closest solution so far, but there are 3 shift per day, and the shift 3 (clock in at 22:00 and clock out at 6:00 at the following day) the query should get the clock out at the following day if the person is on shift 3, but the person on shift 1 and 2 will always have clock in and clock out on same day

Comment: @Yohan Wijayanto, You say there are 3 shifts per day, so I suppose an employee normally work 1 shift per day but possible more at urgent request. But what really bothers me is the business logic towards missing clock-in or clock-out entries. What if a person misses a clock-in or clock-out? How do you record when a person has to work 2 consecutive shifts ?(Do they need to register a clock-in at the first shift and a clock-out at the end of the second shift ? Or a clock-in and a clock for each shift?

Comment: Unless we have a thorough understanding of the business logic, I don't think it's possible to work out a robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want but gives your expected result for the sample data in your question.
(Assumes data type of column DATE_ATT is DATE and data type of TIME_ATT column is TIME. Refer to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html).)

```sql
select EMP_ID
      ,date(min(timestamp(DATE_ATT, TIME_ATT))) as THE_DATE
      ,time(min(timestamp(DATE_ATT, TIME_ATT))) as IN_TIME
      ,time(max(timestamp(DATE_ATT, TIME_ATT))) as OUT_TIME
  from ATT_LOG
 group by EMP_ID
```

Refer to [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/tkzO2FzU) *db<>fiddle* and these SO questions:

- [Creating DATETIME from DATE and TIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318630/creating-datetime-from-date-and-time)
- [How to separate DATE and TIME from DATETIME in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337195/how-to-separate-date-and-time-from-datetime-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each employee only has 2 Att_Log entries a day, your query should just need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT Emp_ID, Date_Att, Min(Time_Att) AS InTime, Max(Time_Att) AS OutTime
FROM Att_Log
GROUP BY Emp_ID, Date_Att
```

That should give you the highest and lowest dates for each day for each employee (rather than the highest and lowest for the whole table).
If you want to manipulate the data-types of the dates, you can try the manipulations posted by Abra.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this should work**

```sql
WITH Att_Log as (
SELECT 'E-0123' as Emp_ID, '2024-01-02' as Date_Att, '08:05:56' as Time_Att UNION ALL
SELECT 'E-0123','2024-01-02','17:02:23' UNION ALL
SELECT 'E-0124','2024-01-02','21:55:56' UNION ALL
SELECT 'E-0124','2024-01-03','06:02:23')

SELECT Emp_ID,DATE(MIN(DATETIME(Date_Att || ' ' || Time_Att))) as Date,TIME(MIN(DATETIME(Date_Att || ' ' || Time_Att))) as In_Time,TIME(MAX(DATETIME(Date_Att || ' ' || Time_Att))) as Out_Time FROM Att_Log
GROUP BY Emp_ID
```

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Probably also a good idea to take the [tour] and visit the [help].